# String contains vs List<String> contains

Tags: java, coding-style, contains

Assuming you want to test if an input is one of several constant Strings, and ignoring performance, is it an anti-pattern to code:

```
if ("yes oui ja da".contains(answer)) {
    // answer was in the affirmative
}
```

instead of the more conventional:

```
private static List<String> affirmativeAnswers = Arrays.asList("yes", "oui", "ja", "da");

if (affirmativeAnswers.contains(answer)) {
    // answer was in the affirmative
}
```

It's a lot less code and easier to read, but is it a "hack"?

#### Edit:

For more safety, if you are worried about partial matches, you can code it as:

```
if (",yes,oui,ja,da,".contains(',' + answer + ','))
```

It's *still* much less code (although getting ugly)

Comment: same thing happens when you use `regex` to search a particular pattern without `boundary`..it's not an hack.it is an error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... is it an abuse of the language ...

"Java - he don't care!!".  But "Eww!!  Nasty!!"<sup>1</sup>.

But seriously, you should be aiming to make your code easy to read and easy to maintain.  (Or performant ... if that matters.)

Tricky, obscure code that expresses something using the minimum number of keystrokes is none of the above.  It is bad style ... even if you get the code functionally correct.

---

<sup>1 - if you've been living under a rock for the past year or so ... I'm alluding to this - http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/honey-badger.</sup>

Comment: Fyi I think the hack is easy to read. That's why I sometimes use it.

Comment: If you think it is easy to read, why are you asking us for an opinion??  But anyway, I'd disagree with that.  It is only easy to read if you already use, and can recognize the idiom.  Think of other people reading your code ...

Comment: Looking back now at my suggestion I am slightly horrified.

Answer (score 5):

I would regard this as an ugly hack, for various reasons:

- It isn't robust to unexpected input. For example `("yes oui ja da".contains(" "))` would return true - probably not what you intended. This is I think the biggest problem. Even if you start adding more tricks (like the commas in the recent edit) then you still have nasty corner cases to consider.
- It isn't as performant in the general case - if you have a medium/large number of possibilities to test for, you are probably better checking against a `HashMap` or `HashSet` which is `O(1)` as opposed to `O(n)` for scanning a concatenated String.
- It might confuse an inexperienced coder/future maintainer. Don't use clever tricks if you want your code to be maintainable.
- It doesn't lend itself well to future refactoring (e.g. internationalisation of Strings? altering the list of possibilities dynamically at runtime?)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for the presence of the string in the sentence, then 
string.contains(string) is feasible.

Else, if you want to check for the equality of whole strings, then,
list.contains(string) is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Also, AFAIK, the String contains method uses regex to check if a substring is a part of a string. And this operation is expensive compared to searching a list (AFAIK). So IMO, it's better to use a list now, isn't it? ;)

Comment: *"Also, AFAIK, the String contains method uses regex..."* No, it doesn't. Of *course* it doesn't. It has no need to. `contains` is just a wrapper around `indexOf(...) > -1` and `indexOf` doesn't use regex either.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I guess I confused contains with replace all. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @ Expressions: Well, yes, `replaceAll` uses regex because the argument you give it is a pattern string.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove dependencies where possible**

In my opinion it is not best practice. Best practice would allow for the removal of the dependency on the acceptance strings. In this case, the dependency is this `("yes", "oui", "ja", "da")` list of strings. However, if the dependency on the list of strings were to be moved to a service or database, it would be very easy to integrate that into a method which accepted `List<string>` because it is obvious, whereas issues could arise when trying to integrate into a method which simply expects a `string`.

**Keep scope in mind**

As always, this depends on scope. If you only needed to do this small thing one time and it was part of a very small project, then it really makes little difference. However, if this is a piece of a project which is not small, then it could require refactoring down the road if best practices were not observed.

**Let the compiler optimize the code**

In regards to the amount of code it takes, you should not worry too much about that. It is more important that it is readable. The compiler will make the code as efficient as possible because that is it's duty. Do not attempt to write code similar to a compiler, because as better approaches emerge, the compiler will use them whereas the emulated code will remain the same.

Comment: I consider it more readable than the list version, that's why I use it occasionally

Comment: @Bohemian - Well, as a 1 liner I can see that, but if you factor this out into a method, then the signature would be more readable if it accepted a list of string. Usually when I find myself using a process more than once I turn it into a method or use a design pattern to encapsulate it. This way there is no room for copy paste errors, the functionality can be expanded upon in the future, and it is easy to test.

Comment: You wouldn't bother creating s method that accepts a lust if string and a string; you would simply in-line it ad list.contsins(sting)